# How to access parameters in .ejs page

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

How can I access latitude and longitude  at my .ejs page in a `<script>` tag?

```js
app.get('/display/:id', function (req, res) 
{
  res.render('home', { latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude })
};
```

and I want to access it at javascript

```js
<script>
var latitude = //code to access latitude
var longitude = //code to access longitude
</script>
```

Comment: try using ```var latitude = <%=latitude%>```